# python executeable created with pyinstaller isnt working

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I tried to compile a python project with pyinstaller into a single executable. Does anyone has a idea why it works when i run the python project, but fails to run when i execute the executable?

My dependecies are down below.

```
Pillow  9.3.0   9.3.0
altgraph    0.17.3  0.17.3
certifi 2022.9.24   2022.9.24
charset-normalizer  2.1.1   3.0.1
contourpy   1.0.6   1.0.6
cycler  0.11.0  0.11.0
fonttools   4.38.0  4.38.0
idna    3.4 3.4
kiwisolver  1.4.4   1.4.4
matplotlib  3.6.2   3.6.2
numpy   1.23.5  1.23.5
nvidia-cublas-cu11  11.10.3.66  11.11.3.6
nvidia-cuda-nvrtc-cu11  11.7.99 11.8.89
nvidia-cuda-runtime-cu11    11.7.99 11.8.89
nvidia-cudnn-cu11   8.5.0.96    8.6.0.163
opencv-python   4.6.0.66    4.6.0.66
packaging   21.3    21.3
pip 21.3.1  22.3.1
pyinstaller 5.6.2   5.6.2
pyinstaller-hooks-contrib   2022.13 2022.13
pyparsing   3.0.9   3.0.9
python-dateutil 2.8.2   2.8.2
requests    2.28.1  2.28.1
setuptools  60.2.0  65.6.3
six 1.16.0  1.16.0
torch   1.13.0  1.13.0
torchvision 0.14.0  0.14.0
typing-extensions   4.4.0   4.4.0
urllib3 1.26.13 1.26.13
wheel   0.38.4  0.38.4
```

I executed it and got this errors:

```
[19507] WARNING: file already exists but should not: /tmp/_MEIF8RVEq/torch/_C.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
[19507] WARNING: file already exists but should not: /tmp/_MEIF8RVEq/torch/_C_flatbuffer.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
torchvision/io/image.py:13: UserWarning: Failed to load image Python extension: 
torch/_jit_internal.py:839: UserWarning: Unable to retrieve source for @torch.jit._overload function: <function _DenseLayer.forward at 0x7fc0c005b8b0>.
  warnings.warn(
torch/_jit_internal.py:839: UserWarning: Unable to retrieve source for @torch.jit._overload function: <function _DenseLayer.forward at 0x7fc0c006fb80>.
  warnings.warn(
torch/serialization.py:834: UserWarning: Couldn't retrieve source code for container of type RRDBNet. It won't be checked for correctness upon loading.
  warnings.warn("Couldn't retrieve source code for container of "
torch/serialization.py:868: SourceChangeWarning: source code of class 'torch.nn.modules.conv.Conv2d' has changed. you can retrieve the original source code by accessing the object's source attribute or set `torch.nn.Module.dump_patches = True` and use the patch tool to revert the changes.
  warnings.warn(msg, SourceChangeWarning)
torch/serialization.py:868: SourceChangeWarning: source code of class 'torch.nn.modules.container.Sequential' has changed. you can retrieve the original source code by accessing the object's source attribute or set `torch.nn.Module.dump_patches = True` and use the patch tool to revert the changes.
  warnings.warn(msg, SourceChangeWarning)
torch/serialization.py:834: UserWarning: Couldn't retrieve source code for container of type RRDB. It won't be checked for correctness upon loading.
  warnings.warn("Couldn't retrieve source code for container of "
torch/serialization.py:834: UserWarning: Couldn't retrieve source code for container of type ResidualDenseBlock. It won't be checked for correctness upon loading.
  warnings.warn("Couldn't retrieve source code for container of "
torch/serialization.py:868: SourceChangeWarning: source code of class 'torch.nn.modules.activation.LeakyReLU' has changed. you can retrieve the original source code by accessing the object's source attribute or set `torch.nn.Module.dump_patches = True` and use the patch tool to revert the changes.
  warnings.warn(msg, SourceChangeWarning)
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you'd add the command which you used to create the executable

Comment: I used `pyinstaller --onefile file.py`

Comment: create a [example]